# In Clojure how do I get the basis for a record with only an instance of the record?

Tags: clojure, record

I have a record in Clojure

```
(defrecord Animal [name age])
```

and I can easily create an instance of the record

```
(def my-cat (Animal. "spot" 2))
```

I can also create an instance with the map->Animal function

```
(def my-dog (map->Animal {:name "snowy" :age 6 :legs 3}))
```

which creates

```
#user.Animal{:name "snowy", :age 6, :legs 3}
```

Given only an instance of `Animal`, eg `my-dog`, how do I get the basis?

I'm aware that I can make a static call on `Animal` to get it, like so:

```
(Animal/getBasis)
```

which gives `[name age]`, but how do I get this from `my-dog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with clojure's handling of static method calling. Here is some code which will get your answer

```
user=> (defrecord Animal [name age])
user.Animal
user=> (def my-dog (map->Animal {:name "snowy" :age 6 :legs 3}))
#'user/my-dog
user=> (. (. (type my-dog) getMethod "getBasis" nil) invoke nil nil)
[name age]
```

There is a longer discussion of this [in another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852133/clojure-vars-and-java-static-methods)

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful. I think the bottom line is a little prettier as `(.. (type my-dog) (getMethod "getBasis" nil) (invoke nil nil))` but the sense is identical.