# Clojure: how do I require a class and call a static method?

Tags: clojure

Just getting into Clojure, and I'm having a little trouble with namespaces, paths and class syntax.

I started by testing and writing a simple hello world function.

test/test_subject_test.clj:

```
(ns test-subject-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [test-subject :refer :all]))

(deftest testit
  (testing "All good?"
    (is (= "I got this" (subject))))
```

src/test_subject.clj:

```
(ns test-subject)

(defn subject []
  "I got this")
```

That all works fine, so I decided to try calling a static method on a class next.

test/test_subject_test.clj:

```
(ns test-subject-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [test-subject :refer :all]
            [hello :refer :all]))

(deftest testit
  (testing "All good?"
    (is (= "I got this" (subject))))
  (testing "Try calling a static method"
    (is (= "Hello Guy!" (-handler Hello "Guy")))))
```

src/hello.clj:

```
(ns hello
  (:gen-class :name "Hello"
              :methods [^:static [handler [String] String]]))

(defn -handler [s]
  (str "Hello " s "!"))
```

But now the compiler throws a long stack trace with one interesting message: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: Hello in this context`. I've tried a few permutations of the `:require` statement and the `(-handler Hello)` call, I've tried not using `:refer :all` and referring to the method as `(-handler (.Hello hello))` but clearly I'm missing something really basic about how classes work in Clojure.

I had a look at [Clojure vars and Java static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852133/clojure-vars-and-java-static-methods), but it seems way more complex than necessary for what I am trying to do: just call a static method. However, there was one interesting quote in the question, which led me to try this: `(Hello handler "Guy")` without success (Unable to resolve symbol: Hello in this context).

So, how should I require a class from another file and call a static method on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this is slightly different if you're compiling a class into the default package (which is what you're doing here) since you can't import those classes. I don't recommend you do that. In the following code I'm pretending you actually wrote `(:gen-class :name "hello.Hello" ...)`

To call methods on a java class you should either use the fully qualified classname or first `import` the class:

```
(import 'hello.Hello)
(Hello/handler "there")
```

or

```
(hello.Hello/handler "there")
```

As you can see, you should use / to call static methods on java classes.

For this all to work with gen-class you must make sure that the classes are compiled first. The simplest way to guarantee *that* is to `require` its namespace first:

```
(require 'hello)
(import 'hello.Hello)
```

Because this is all more trouble than using plain clojure functions & namespaces, you *probably* shouldn't be using java interop if you're only intending to call the code from clojure.

Comment: Yeah, I'm only using interop because the my first Clojure apps will be AWS Lambda "functions", and Lambda expects a Java class with a static `.handler` method.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a static method, you should be invoking it with the `/` separator.

For example:

```
(System/currentTimeMillis)
```

In your case, the following should work:

```
(ns other
  (:require [hello :as hello]))

(hello/-handler "FOO")
; => "Hello FOO!"
```

For reference: http://clojure.org/java_interop