# Calling a Java static function from Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a java package com.example.Api

I have included it in my project.clj

I have imported it:

```
(ns prismic-clojure.core
  (:import [com.example.Api])
  (:gen-class))
```

There is a static 'get' function which, in Java, I would access like:

```
Api api = Api.get("https://my.company.io/api", "secret-token");
```

The java function is defined as:

```
public static Api get(String url, String accessToken)
```

I have tried this:

```
(def api (. get Api "https://my.company.io/api" "secret-token") )
```

Comment: If it's a **method**, not a static function, then you need to actually create an `Api` instance. What's the calling convention for the constructor for that class?

Comment: (It would also be a good starting point to show what you've tried).

Comment: it is a static function. added detail to question above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clojure: how do I require a class and call a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821340/clojure-how-do-i-require-a-class-and-call-a-static-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you call a static function on the `Api` class:

```
(Api/get "https://my.company.io/api" "secret-token")
```