# Clojure call to static Java method of anonymous class

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have a set of Java classes that all implement the `newBuilder` interface (they are actually protobuf generated classes). I would like to pass the class as a parameter to a form that returns a function to create a new builder for that class.

```
(defn create-message-builder
  [klass]
  (. klass newBuilder))
```

I cannot get the form dynamically so that it calls the `newBuilder` static method on `klass`.

I found a macro on [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852133/clojure-vars-and-java-static-methods) and made some modifications to support injecting it into my source:

```
(defmacro jcall [obj & args]
  `(let [ref (if (and (symbol? ~obj) 
                     (instance? Class (eval ~obj)))
          (eval ~obj)
          ~obj) ]
  (. ref# ~@args)))
```

When I attempt to call this macro:

```
repl> (jcall Contact newBuilder)
#object[com.skroot.Contact$Builder 0x5622de90 ""]
```

I get an error:

> IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: newBuilder for class java.lang.Class

Comment: Also it's not an anonymous class at all. You just don't know its name at compile time because you're passed a Class object at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same thing you would do in Java: use reflection to ask the Class object what methods it has, find the one of the right name, and call it with no arguments.

```
(defn class->builder [c]
  (let [m (.getDeclaredMethod c "newBuilder" (into-array Class []))]
    (.invoke m nil (into-array Object []))))
```